# Accepting answer Vs Keeping it open for a question where you didn't get a satisfactory answer

Tags: discussion

I often get comments in my new questions (possibly from StackOverFlow admins) that I need to work on my accept rate. However for the questions that were open, they are open questions for which I didn't get a satisfactory answer.

So for some question I did get an answer but they were of not much help in my context, so for those question I explored other alternatives. What is the best way for this situation, should I just close the question or accept closest answer for a comment.

Anything that can keep me off the administrator's pokes :)

Comment: Ignore the comments about accept rate; they are never from moderators (moderators have a ♦ (diamond) next to their name). Flag them if you find them disruptive or offensive. SO encourages you to mark answers as accepted, but it doesn't force you!

Comment: I only found two such comments on your questions, both of which I flagged and both were removed (a threshold for flagging was reached, often that threshold is very low for 'accept rate' comments). They were *not* from any 'admin'.

Comment: "so for those question I explored other alternatives" - If those alternatives have solved your problem in another way, you should consider posting them as an answer and accepting that instead of the existing one's on your quesitons.

Comment: Regarding "possibly from StackOverFlow admins": generally, the only people who are "admins" have usernames with diamonds on the end, like [BoltClock♦](http://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock). We call them "moderators" here. The exception is that some employees of Stack Exchange (the company that handles the code and operation of the site) may not have the diamond, but if they were speaking officially, they'd surely tell you so. Other than that, all users are just normal, like you, no matter how big the numbers by their names are.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that you'll be getting comments from Stack Overflow "admins" referring to your accept rate. Such comments are usually not constructive and should be flagged as such.

You don't have to accept an answer if non of the answers helped you solve the problem. However, if an answer *did* help you then you should accept that answer.

If the problem still exists then you shouldn't close it either.

Answer (score 4):

We always hear from people complaining about people's accept rate, so here's the other side.

Your accept rate on Stack Overflow is 53% (as of this writing). Not bad, but an indication that maybe you need to look at the types of questions you are asking if half the time you are not getting answers.

I browsed through some of your questions, and I admit that I don't know the technology you are using, but the questions I looked at were very vague. There's no specific issue and sometimes you are simply asking for advice. Most of the unanswered questions have no sample code but are simply text blobs that require a lot of effort for someone unfamiliar with the issue to comprehend. Many of these questions could be closed as "Not A Real Question".

I understand that sample code isn't a requirement, but for me, no sample code in a question is a huge red flag that the question most likely isn't specific enough.

> However for the questions that were open, they are open questions for which I didn't get a satisfactory answer.

If you didn't get an answer you were willing to accept, please consider

- adding some (more) sample code to illustrate your problem
- stating your goal instead of just saying where you are stuck
- telling us what you were doing before the problem occurred. If you changed any settings or code, *say so*
- changing the tags or title to better reflect the problem you are having
- using a test case to demonstrate the problem, instead of posting your exact issue
- showing before and after examples
- refining your problem to ask for something *specific*

What I have found is that when people don't get an answer, it's usually because they have the XY problem. Don't tell us where you are stuck. Tell us what your goal is and ask for help with *that*.

Also, you usually get very poor answers when asking for large sections of code, or something that isn't specific. And some questions just beg for [link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/147645).

> What is the best way for this situation, should I just close the question or accept closest answer for a comment.

If someone's answer didn't directly answer your question, but led you to a solution, you should post your solution as an answer (and accept it, of course) and *state how the other person's answer helped you*. This is so others who come across the same issue can see how you solved it.

Answer (score 3):

It is highly unlikely that moderators would be poking you to accept answers just for improving your accept rate. This has been discussed on meta several times and I have read answers where poking by anyone, let alone moderators has been highly discouraged.

If none of the answer(s) is satisfactory, or helped you in any way, you should not accept any.

If you were able to solve the problem yourself you should post an answer yourself and accept it. If an answer partially helped me I would refer to that answer in my answer and mention the additional steps.

You can leave the question open if you neither got a satisfactory answer, nor were you able to solve it yourself.

There are [various thread on accepting an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=accepting%20answers), where you can read more about this.